# declaring global variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

My question might be quite basic, have not been able to find any answer to it on internet though. I have created an object oriented program in Matlab. When running the model I would like to have time as a global variable that can be accessed by all objects. How are variables declared as Global in Matlab. According to the advice given by Matlab it should simply be declared like this:

```
global time
```

this however gives the following error message:

```
parse error at global: usage might be invalid matlab syntax.
```

What’s the right way to do it?

Comment: That's one line of code out of context. Where is it? Inside each of the class constructors?

Answer (score 4):

I can only guess that you added the `global` keyword to a place it should not be, in C++ style. The following is **illegal** Matlab syntax:

```
 classdef MyClass
       global time;
 end
```

In Matlab the `global` keyword is put inside functions only:

```
 classdef MyClass
     methods
         function foo(this)
             global time;
         end

         function bar(this)
             global time;
         end
     end
 end
```

Comment: If function foo create `global` variable name `time` and in function bar, just redo `global time;` and you'll get access to the same variable data. The global can be anything : object, array, int, handle,...